# MYSQL?PHP using variables to replace filenames in insert statements

Tags: mysql, variables, insert, field

I have a page that inserts records into a database file called ports that holds two fields, called id and port.
The data is checked by an include, checkform.php, that strips out any bad data and blank entries.
It works fine, and as I have more data files of a similar construction it seems logical to use the same page for inserting records by passing the file and field names to the page as parameters.
The SQL that is used for the stand alone page is:

```
$sql='INSERT IGNORE INTO ports(port) VALUES(?)';
```

I want to do some thing like:

```
$sql='INSERT IGNORE INTO $filename ($fieldname) VALUES(?)';
```

I have looked on the forum and found many solutions that do not appear to work
Like :

```
$sql='INSERT IGNORE INTO '$filename' ('$fieldname') VALUES(?)';

$sql='INSERT IGNORE INTO "'$filename'" ("'$fieldname'") VALUES(?)';

$sql='INSERT IGNORE INTO `$filename` (`$fieldname`) VALUES(?)';
```

as well as :

```
$sql="INSERT IGNORE INTO `$filename` (`$fieldname`) VALUES (`$fieldname`);";
```

and many others. The combination seems endless, and so far I would have been better just copying the pages and changing the variables by hand. The code for the insert is below:

```
    // check if form submitted and has a value
    If  (isset($_POST['insert']))
    {   require('../includes/checkform.inc.php');   
    // continue if the field is OK
    if (empty($missing)) // ** missing is empty if the data is clean and exists
    { // process the input.
        require_once('../includes/connection.inc.php');
        // initialize a flag
        $OK = false;
        //create database connection
        $conn = mysqli_connect( $DatabaseServer,$DatabaseUser, $DatabasePassword, $DatabaseName);
        // Initialize prepared statement
        $stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
        //create SQL 
        $sql='INSERT IGNORE INTO ports(port) VALUES(?)'; //#
        //bind parameters and execute statement
            if($stmt->prepare($sql)) {
             $stmt->bind_param('s',$_POST['port']);//#
            $stmt->execute(); 
            if ($stmt->affected_rows > 0)
             $OK = true;
            }//if $tmt
    }// if empty
    // redirect if successful or display an error - on page below
    if ($OK) {
        header('Location:insertok.php');
    exit;
        } else {

        $error = htmlspecialchars($stmt->error);
```

The lines with  //# against them are the ones that I need help with.
Most of the code is modified from a book by David Powers.
Howard Walker

Answer (score 0):

To interpolate variables in a string, you have to use double quotes `"$var"`. Note that you shouldn't surround $var with single quotes. And your table and column names might be one of the reserved words. It complains when that happens. You use backticks to escape the reserved words.

```
$sql="INSERT IGNORE INTO `$filename` (`$fieldname`) VALUES (?);";
```

This should work just fine.

**EDIT**

Your file/field might also include the characters that mySQL doesn't like. In that case, escape the query string before executing it. Refer: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

```
$sql = $stmt->real_escape_string($sql);
```

Comment: But it does not unfortunately. It has to be of the format     $sql="INSERT IGNORE INTO $filename ($fieldname) VALUES(?); because the following prepared statement needs it in that way I think? Whatever way I try to parse the sql, I always get the following error: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '()VALUES (?)' at line 1. When I just type in the field names it works perfectly.

Comment: I can assure you the syntax here is right. However, what comes to mind is that your file/field names might be including mySQL Reserve words. So the solutions you find with the backtick are to escape those keywords. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: to clear our doubts, pls check if your data might include any of these keywords http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: There are no reserved words on the site as it has been running for many years using PHP. I have yet to implement the real_escape_string, but I doubt that it will make any difference, as the only words that I have been inputting are "testport" and "testport2". I don't think it is to do with the data or the filenamee. I even constructed a string and passed it to the $QL= statement. It does not work with variables, but it does if I put the actual field names in a string and pass that to $QL=

Comment: Your syntax is definitely correct. Unfortunately my typing is not! While making modifications to the code to follow your syntax, I used Spost instead of $_POST in three locations,which was why my updated code did not function. Proves the basic rule - check your typing. Thanks a lot for your help. All now up and running.

Comment: glad i could be of help. If the answer or comment is helpful, pls upvote it. Thanks. :)